# How do you determine the following coefficient?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$$[x^n]\frac{(1+x)^n}{(1-x)}$$

It seems pretty simple but I can't seem to find it. I tried rewriting it as the product of two sums. $(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^n$ and $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+...$ but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want the $n$'th coefficient of $(1+x)^n(1+x+x^2+\dots )$

It should be clear this coefficient is equal to the sum of the coefficients of $(1+x)^n$, which is $2^n$.

Comment: Why should that be clear? Is some theorem that explains that? Thank you.

Comment: the $n$'th coefficient in the product of formal power series $a_i$ and $b_i$ is $\sum_{i=0}^n a_ib_{n-i}$

Comment: @Joanpemo: A very useful fact to remember is that when you convolve a sequence $\sigma$ with the constant sequence $\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$, you get the sequence of partial sums of $\sigma$. In terms of generating functions this convolution is multiplication by $\frac1{1-x}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much. Both comments really helped a lot. Do you have some good reference for this matierial?

Comment: @Joanpemo: You’re welcome. Chapter $7$ of Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*, is a pretty good introduction and basic reference, and the whole book is well worth having. A more compressed but also more focussed reference is Herbert S. Wilf, *generatingfunctionology*; the second edition is freely available in PDF form [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here we use the [coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216) operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.

\begin{align*}
[x^k](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> [x^n]\frac{(1+x)^n}{1-x}&=[x^n]\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x^j(1+x)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n}[x^{n-j}](1+x)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{n-j}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\\
> &=2^n
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the geometric series representation
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x^j
  \end{align*}
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and the rule
  \begin{align*}
  [x^{n+m}]A(x)=[x^n]x^{-m}A(x)
  \end{align*}
  Since the exponent of $x^{n-j}$ is bounded by $0\leq n-j \leq n$ due to $0\leq j \leq n$ we restrict the upper limit of the series by $n$.